# .append() not working while dynamically binding images for image slider

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asmx

I'm trying to make a dynamic image slider using asp.net C# and jquery. I have stored image paths in database and have fetched those image paths to bind on page load where these images paths are supposed to work showing the respective images on my web page. I have used Really Simple Slider plugin that I found on internet and I am binding images using json response as below:

```
    'output' is my json response which holds a string array that contains the image names that I'm using to complete an image path.

    $("#slider1").append('<div class="main"><div class="rss-container"><div id="slideshow" class="rs-slideshow"><div class="slide-container">');
    $("#slider1").append('<img src="beeSlider/images/'+output.d[0]+ '" alt=""/></div><ol class="slides">');

        $.each(output.d, function (key, value) {
        $("#slider1").append('<li><a href="beeSlider/images/'+value+'"></a></li>');
        });

    $("#slider1").append('</ol></div></div></div>');
```

The binding with output.d[0] has worked. But the code within $.each aint working at all. That just shows bullets. This should be retrieving images rather than just those bullets.
Can anybody help me to solve this one. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You werent putting them in image tags...

```
$("#slider1").append('<div class="main"><div class="rss-container"><div id="slideshow" class="rs-slideshow"><div class="slide-container">');
    $("#slider1").append('<img src="beeSlider/images/'+output.d[0]+ '" alt=""/></div><ol class="slides">');

        output.d.forEach(function (value) {
        $("#slider1").append('<img src="beeSlider/images/'+value+'" />');
        });

    $("#slider1").append('</ol></div></div></div>');
```

Comment: Thanks @Micah, that worked to load all the images but the classes donot seem to be working. I mean, images are supposed to be sliding following .js file that has been included in the .aspx page where I'm viewing my slider, but images have been only enlisted in sequence. Shouldn.t they be acquiring the css classes and jquery file that has been included in .aspx page?

Comment: @accssharma In that case you might need to share the #slider1 html and css. And I think you can mark this as an answer and ask a new question

Comment: And to be mentioned, as I am using a ready made plugin, it is tracking count of <li> and images inside <li> in <a href=""></a>. That will be so much time consuming task to do manual changes which is like impossible. It is a working solution for some cases, but it seems to be not working for my case. Anything I should try?

Comment: I dont understand what you're saying. if you need the images to be inside an `<li>` then just modify the image append line so that the tags are inside of `li` tags.... this really should be it

Comment: I got your point but there are more dependencies. May be I'll ask another question. Thanks :).